# multidimensional array indexing changing values of my matrices

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidimensional array with 13,057 8X11 matrices inside it.

```
dim(results)
[1] 13057     8    11
```

Every time I to index a particular matrix, the values inside the matrix change. For example, say I do:

```
head(results)
[1] 0.2789366 0.1555067 0.3026808 0.1644631 0.2325074 0.3162973
```

but when I do

```
results[1,,]

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
[1,] 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366 0.2789366
[2,] 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516 0.1191516
[3,] 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271 0.1805271
[4,] 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702 0.1846702
[5,] 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454 0.4004454
[6,] 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974 0.1336974
[7,] 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045 0.2155045
[8,] 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715 0.5307715
```

Why are my all of my rows having the same value? This is NOT what the initial value of this matrix was before I put it in the multidimensional array nor is it the value I get when I print all of the matrices in the console.

This is my code:

```
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
results = array(0,dim=c(13057,8,11))

for( i in 1:13057) {
  ap <- as.numeric(unlist(ap.dv[i,1:11]))
  dv <- as.numeric(unlist(ap.dv[i,12:19]))
  m <- outer(ap, dv, FUN="*")
  m[is.na(m)] <- 0
  m <- range01(m)
  results[] <- m
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under any array or matrix, is really just a vector.
When you call `head` on an array, you are not geting the head of the first matrix, you are getting the head of the vector.   Look at the ordering of the letters below

```
> LL <- LETTERS[1:24]
> dim(LL) <- c(2, 3, 4)
> head(LL)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"

## Have a look at LL: 

> LL
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "C"  "E" 
[2,] "B"  "D"  "F" 

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "G"  "I"  "K" 
[2,] "H"  "J"  "L" 

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "M"  "O"  "Q" 
[2,] "N"  "P"  "R" 

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "S"  "U"  "W" 
[2,] "T"  "V"  "X"
```

---

Play with `LL` above, have a look at the first element, `LL[[1]]`, the seoncd, `LL[[2]]`, etc.

Have a look at the difference between `LL[1, , ]` and `LL[, , 1]`. 
What you may think of as "the first matrix" is not necessarily what `R` would consider such.

---

As for your question of why you have repeated values, the answer is that you are actually assigning these values yourself.  Or rather, you are assigning a smaller (less dim) array, and R is recycling.

Instead of `results[] <- m`, use `results[i, , ] <- m`

Comment: I'm basically trying to put ~13,000 matrices (that are 8X11) into a multidimensional array. So if my array looks like this: 

> results = array(0,dim=c(13057,8,11))

when I use 

> results[1,,] 

I should get out an 8X11 matrix at position 1 in the array. If I do what you suggested, I get out ~13,000 lines, 1 for each matrix in the array. 

I'm trying to keep these matrices in the array to then plot interesting matrices. But when I try to plot a matrix, I get nonsense because the values are all the same like my example above.

Comment: I'm basically just looking for a way to store a bunch of matrices in an array and to then just index them based on the position in which they occupy in the array. How can I do this?

Comment: @user3067923 `R` is recycling becuase you are not providing enough values.  See the edit above